# How to use VoIP in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, voip

I have to build a mobile App (iOS)  for people with Dementia. When they get lost, they start the App and there will be a simple HELP Button for them. When they pressed this Button, the App will build a connection with someone from their family, who can help them. The “Supervisor” can see 2 Cameras - Front + Back Camera view of the Caller + his Location on Map.

Is it possible to make this App? It's my University Project. Could someone give me some tips on how can I make this App step by step - things like this VoIP Connection and so on? I would really appreciate it because I have no idea where to start. I have already made some Apps for iOS but I have never worked with things like VoIP

Thanks!

Comment: Its all possible, but you're asking too many things covering too much functionality at once for a question. Its also very ambitious for a university project, perhaps too much so.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is using a third party service built on WebRTC which provides the infrastructure. They do cost a bit but the free tiers will probably be enough and if you go over the free levels your app is probably getting used.

https://webrtc.org/

I just built an enterprise app using TokBok which was the best choice when I started. Having said that Twilio is a great company and was in Beta with their toolkit. It has been released since. You may want to look at that. It is probably a better choice overall although I have not personally used the video component.

Lastly i did a search and ran into another choice, Sinch, which looks good but have not really looked at.

https://tokbox.com  https://www.twilio.com/video https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/ios-video-calling/

TokBox have samples in Objective C and good tutorials. You can just use their apps as a starting point. I used Swift but the have sample there also

https://github.com/thepatrick/Opentok-HelloWorld-Swift

One advantage of Twilio is that they are have support for phone connections which TokBox does not have and that Twilio is a great choice for SMS messaging and push notifications. They also have a great web service to drive phone calls. In this way you could have the backend send a text message, a notification and a phone call to a group of people.

They also have better examples for Swift which is a better choice than Objective C if you are not already an expert in Object c.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SDK is available for voip and many more funcationality.

Please visit twilio tutorial :
[Twilio iOS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios)